# Amazon EC2+Nodejs+DynamoDB for Chat-Web-Mobile application

Tags: php, node.js, chat, amazon-dynamodb

I want to set up a chat application(based on PHP and nodejs), database will be DynamoDB. Data for this web application will be very big(billions of rows), users will be more than 10 millions
The requirements: 
**- Users can go to website and chat in there(both in web and mobile devices)

- Users from Asia Region and US Region have to be route in there Region when enter the web/chat**

Region will increase in the future, now I got the problem with synchronize data between 2 region instances, also the performance of application. This is 2 solutions I found:

1. Use 2 instances with 2 dynamodb and then use Route 53 to route traffic, but the problem is I dont know how nodejs server with synchronize data with 2 databases
2. Use 2 instances with 1 dynamodb(but I dont know which region to put data because the performance will be not good)

One more thing: I'll use S3 to store resource but Im afraid about the loading speed in too many regions(in the future).

Any ideas to improve this solutions?

[image]

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise. You may want to find a development forum (perhaps [quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Most of your users on the chat platform will center around a particular region. I think you can have the best of both solutions. Use [cross region replication](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.CrossRegionRepl.html) to synchronize changes in two DynamoDB tables, one in each region. You can do this with your own lambda functions or the [cross-region replication library](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-cross-region-library). So you can master the users that create their accounts in Asia in an AWS region in Asia, and master the accounts created in the US in an AWS region in North America. Then, on the lambda functions you set up, only propagate changes to items that are not mastered in the other table (so that you do not infinite loop in streams writing to each other).